# Partition into two product free sets

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

> Find the smallest integer $k \geq 2$ such that for every partition of
>   the set $\{2, 3,..., k\}$ into two parts, at least one of these parts
>   contains (not necessarily distinct) numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ with $ab
>  = c$.

I think the answer is 32.

My solution: Assume to the contrary. Put 2 in, say, set A. 4 must be in set B. 16 must be in set A. If 8 is in set A, then $2 \cdot 8 =16 \implies$ Contradiction. If 8 is in set B, then $2 \cdot 16=8 \cdot 4 =32 \implies$ Contradiction.
It's simple but a little tedious to find a set with $k=31$ that doesn't work- the trick's to put the primes (and 16) together. Here's one:
$(2,3,5,7,11,13,16,17,21,23,29,31)$ and $(4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,18,19,20,22,24,25,26,27,28,30)$.

Is there a better and more formalized explanation than this?

Comment: In the statement of the problem do you mean ab=c?

Comment: @S.Dolan It was a mistake editing it, it would be $ ab = c $

Comment: Thanks - I've corrected this.

Comment: You switched $19$ and $21$. Also, your example doesn't work since $4 \cdot 6 = 24$. Take $A = (2, 3, 5, 16, 24, 28)$ and $B = (4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31)$. To convince yourself that this is good, notice that in $B$, $6 \cdot 6 > 31, 4 \cdot 8 > 31$, so only $4 \cdot 4 = 16$, $4 \cdot 6 = 24$ and $4 \cdot 7 = 28$ can make problems, but they are in $A$. Similar argument works for $A$. Otherwise, I think your solution is perfectly well formalised.

Comment: @prosinac I think you're absolutely right about my mistake. But I still believe there is a better solutionBut I still believe there is a better solution

Comment: @prosinac. Yes, that's a nice way to ensure that  ab=c cannot occur. Having seen your comment I've added a similar split to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked particularly about your opening argument. It looks good to me - I tried writing out a proof and the best I could come up with is as follows:-

$2^2=4$ and $4^2=16$ and so the set not containing $4$ must contain both $2$ and $16$. Then $8=\frac{16}{2}$ is in the same set as $4$. But now $32=2\times 16=4\times 8$ cannot be in either set.

In the second part you could perhaps say that for $k<31$ simply restrict any solution for $31$ to the smaller numbers.

A simple split is $A=\{2,3\}\cup\{x|x\ge16\}, B=\{x|4\le x<16\}$.